# Objective-C. Block that returns a string and printing it out

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Just got my first job as a Junior iOS. I am going to work with Objective-C a lot which I have little familiarity with, therefore I hope you can forgive me these simple questions.

I had this bit of code:

```
NSString* (^greetings)(void) = ^{
return @"Hello Everyone";
};
```

Not sure how to handle it. In Swift, I could perhaps assign the result of that closure to a variable of type String and print it out.
In Objective-C I am trying to do this:

```
NSString *greetingsAsString = [universalGreetingReturningNSString copy];
NSLog(@"%@", greetingsAsString);
```

and I get this:
<**NSGlobalBlock**: 0x100008198>

Many thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually calling the block, which you do with `()`:

```
NSString* (^greetings)(void) = ^{
    return @"Hello Everyone";
};

NSLog(@"%@", greetings());
                      ^^
```